# Is there a framework for .NET that supports Erlang's concept of "mobile code"?

Tags: .net, serialization, erlang, closures

In other words, "A serialization framework for closures and their set of (IL-code) dependencies".

Comment: Expression<T> seems close, but I haven't tried serializing it as of yet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx

Comment: I guess for the Iron* language family this could work just fine if the same referred assemblies are loaded at the target execution site. Has anyone tried this yet?

Comment: That's a very interesting topic, the only example I've heard of is second life migrating mono scripts between nodes. Apparently they use Mono.Cecil to rewrite the bytecode to yield periodically and if the assembly needs to be migrated they serialise the stack and heap and ship it over.
The second life team haven't released the code for this though, or any technical information on how they do it for that matter. 
Best reference I found from googling was slide 8 in this pdf (http://weblog.savanne.be/files/fosdem-mono-2010/secondlife.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nessos.Vagabond** looks like the first .NET framework that implements dynamic serialization, distribution, and remote execution of .NET code:

http://nessos.github.io/Vagabond/

Answer (score 1):

Check out F#, I think that's the closest "native" .NET language to Erlang or the other functional languages.